# Using Labels from Maplex engine inside ArcGIS Explorer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-explorer, maplex

I'm trying to display data in the upper left and upper right corners of this parcel data.  I can get it to work inside ArcMap with the Maplex engine, but when I save a layer file and open it in arc explorer it puts the two labels back in the middle.

Any ideas how I can get those to stay in the corner of each parcel?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Maplex is not supported by ArcGIS Explorer (I couldn't find this clearly documented anywhere though). What you could do as a workaround is convert your labels to an annotation feature class in ArcMap, then exporting the annotations as layer file. And export the parcels to a .lyr separately, without labels.